# Solving diag$ \left( \textit{A} \textit{X} \right) = \textbf{b}$ for first column of $\textit{X}$ under further constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, inverse-problems

$\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\textit{#1}} $

Consider 
an $n \times m$ matrix $\matr{A}$, 
an $m \times n$ matrix $\matr{X}$,
an $m \times 1$ vector $\textbf{x}$, and 
an $n \times 1$ vector $\textbf{b}$, where
$n \leq m$ and
all entries of $\matr{A}$ and $\textbf{b}$ are real and nonnegative.

Furthermore, $\textbf{x}$ is the first column of $\matr{X}$, and 
diag$\left(\matr{A}\matr{X} \right) = \textbf{b}$.

Given $\matr{A}$, $\textbf{b}$, and the fact that the entries of $\matr{X}$

$\begin{equation}
    x_{i,j} = 
    \begin{cases}
      0,       & \text{if}\ i<j \\
      x_{i-j}, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation},
$

and the entries of $\matr{X}$

$\begin{equation}
    a_{i,j} = 
    \begin{cases}
      0,       & \text{if}\ i>j \\
      a_{i,j}, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}.
$

(1) Under what conditions is there a solution (or range of solutions) for $\textbf{x}$?

(2) How can we solve for $\textbf{x}$ (or range of solutions) given that the conditions are met?

I am not sure how to go about an analytic solution. So far I approximate solutions using Monte-Carlo methods. It seems like it's an underdetermined system, but for many values of $\textbf{b}$ there doesn't seem to be a solution for $\textbf{x}$. Any help/hints are greatly appreciated!

In case my notation is unclear, here is a simple example for $n=3$, $m=4$.

$
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{0,0} & a_{0,1} & a_{0,2} & a_{0,3}\\
    0       & a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3}\\
    0       & 0       & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3}
  \end{bmatrix}
$,
$
X=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{0} & 0     & 0       \\
    x_{1} & x_{0} & 0       \\
    x_{2} & x_{1} & x_{0}   \\
    x_{3} & x_{2} & x_{1}
  \end{bmatrix}
$,
$
\textbf{x}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{0} \\
    x_{1} \\
    x_{2} \\
    x_{3}
  \end{bmatrix}
$,
$
\textbf{b}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    b_{0} \\
    b_{1} \\
    b_{2} \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
$

To check a solution, given:

$
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    0 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
    0 & 0 & 8 & 9
  \end{bmatrix}
$,
$
\textbf{b}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    30 \\
    38 \\
    26 \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
$,

one possible solution is
$
\textbf{x}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    3 \\ 
    4
  \end{bmatrix}
$
and
$
X=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0   \\
    2 & 1 & 0   \\
    3 & 2 & 1   \\
    4 & 3 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}
$
.